# lodash fails on the nested groupBy

Tags: node.js, express, lodash

I have a dataset like this:

```
 var data = [ { keyword: 'organizational inertia',
                project: 'org_inertia',
                target: 'A' },
              { keyword: 'agent based model organization',
                project: 'abm_org',
                target: 'A' },
              { keyword: 'organizational inertia',
                project: 'org_inertia',
                target: 'B' },
              { keyword: 'organizational inertia',
                project: 'org_inertia',
                target: 'C' },
              { keyword: 'organization inertia',
                project: 'org_inertia',
                target: 'A' } ]
```

And a simple code that does this:

```
const result = _.chain(data)
                .groupBy('project')
                .mapValues(values => _.chain(values)
                 .groupBy('target')
                 .mapValues(values => _.join(_.map(values, 'keyword'),', '))
                 .value()
                )
                .value()
```

Giving back the expected result of:

```
{
  abm_org: {
   A: "agent based model organization"
},
  org_inertia: {
    C: "organizational inertia",
    A: "organizational inertia, organization inertia",
    B: "organizational inertia"
  }
}
```

So far so good, on JFiddle works perfect. However, when I port the code on my Express application running on Node (v14.15.5), the result is different:

```
{ 
  org_inertia: { 
    undefined: 'organizational inertia, organizational inertia, organizational inertia, organization inertia' },
  abm_org: { 
    undefined: 'agent based model organization' 
  } 
}
```

It is like if the second groupBy doesn't recognise the keys (but the name is correct)... any hint of why that might happen?

Comment: What lodash version are you using in your Node program?

Comment: "lodash": "^4.17.20" in my package.json

Comment: npm lodash -v
6.14.11

Comment: hm, I tried using loash 4.17.20 in node on my end and your code seems to work. Could it be possible that `data` isn't actually what you think it is when you run your code in Node?

Comment: nope, unfortunately `data` is exactly what I wrote in the question... like copy/pasted from `console.log(data)`

Comment: @NickParsons what is your Node version?

Comment: I am running v14.15.3, but I doubt that's making a big difference...

Answer (score 1):

the error I had was related to my mongoose model for the object I was trying to operate with.

fixing the model by adding the `target` field fixed the problem. @Nick Parsons you where right!